# Copying files with certain title or a title with the keyword 'log' from an S3 bucket to a folder in another bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, copy

I am trying to copy pdf files that contain the keyword 'log' on their titles. I have the command below. What am I missing?

aws s3api copy-object --copy-source  --key 'Log' --bucket

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to change things around and ended up with this that worked.

aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/ s3://destination-bucket/ --recursive  --exclude "*" --include "*log*"